# C: Semaphores - How to release a semaphore after n callbacks only

Tags: c, thread-safety, semaphore

I have a thread where I want to wait (at a particular line of code) for three callback events from another thread. Only after these three events are received then I want to proceed forward.

I am trying to use semaphores. I am aware that a semaphore can be locked at a point and it keeps waiting till it is released by some other thread. 
Now, the thing is that I want to wait for three callbacks and not just one before i release the semaphore.
I thought of having a counter but I am not sure whether just have a separate counter would be thread safe. 
So is there a way to have a semaphore with a thread safe counter?

This is for both Linux and Windows.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the OS , linux or windows ?

Comment: Semaphores do represent integers that are atomically updated. The operations: [wait](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_wait) and [post/signal](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_post) decrement and increment the internal counter respectively. So you don't need to maintain an additional `counter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the threads can have assignable numbers, you maybe can have just a boolean variable per controlling thread and then check if all are set before the suspended thread is released. Writing a byte is probably atomic.

Normal semaphores would have atomic counters, however.